# For parallel algorithm with N threads, can performance gain be more than N?

Tags: performance, algorithm, parallel-processing, theory

A theoretical question, maybe it is obvious:

Is it possible that an algorithm, after being implemented in a parallel way with N threads, will be executed *more than N times* faster than the original, single-threaded algorithm? In other words, can the gain be better that linear with number of threads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not common, but it most assuredly *is* possible.

Consider, for example, building a software pipeline where each step in the pipeline does a fairly small amount of calculation, but requires enough static data to approximately fill the entire data cache -- but each step uses different static data.

In a case like this, serial calculation on a single processor will normally be limited primarily by the bandwidth to main memory. Assuming you have (at least) as many processors/cores (each with its own data cache) as pipeline steps, you can load each data cache *once*, and process one packet of data after another, retaining the same static data for all of them. Now your calculation can proceed at the processor's speed instead of being limited by the bandwidth to main memory, so the speed improvement could easily be 10 times greater than the number of threads.

Theoretically, you could accomplish the same with a single processor that just had a really huge cache. From a practical viewpoint, however, the selection of processors and cache sizes is fairly limited, so if you want to use more cache you need to use more processors -- and *the* way most systems provide to accomplish this is with multiple threads.

Comment: You see this sometimes too when going to multiple nodes, and now having multiple memory bandwidths / network pipes / I/O pipes to access -- if contention for those were the initial bottleneck, you can briefly see superlinear speedups for exactly the reason Jerry's described above.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

I saw an algorithm for moving a robot arm through complicated maneuvers that was basically to divide into N threads, and have each thread move more or less randomly through the solution space.  (It wasn't a *practical* algorithm.)  The statistics clearly showed a superlinear speedup over one thread.  Apparently the probability of hitting a solution over time rose fairly fast and then leveled out some, so the advantage was in having a lot of initial attempts.

Comment: Interesting point! Modern SAT solvers often employ agressive restart strategies precisely for this reason.

Comment: @missingno: sounds interesting, can you give some references?

Comment: The basic idea is that for NP complete problems the length-to-solve distribution is heavily skewed towards to exponential worst case (against the very easy best-case-scenario). However, I can't think of any good references out of the top of my mind other then the complete-overkill [sat handbook](http://www.satlive.org/) (see sidebar). SAT is deep man... Anyway, it doesn't hurt mentioning [Minisat](http://minisat.se/Papers.html).

Comment: This doesn't require multiple threads, though. You could implement that using one thread and something that resembles context switching. That is, compute part of one computation, then part of second one, etc.

Comment: @svick: congratulations, you've just re-invented user-mode threads.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, the point is, those “threads” would run on one actual thread and so they would use only one CPU core. That means the speedup is because of using different algorithm, not because of having more cores available. (I wouldn't actually implement it this way, unless there was a good reason to do so.)

Comment: @svick:  Nope; the original algorithm was doing a semi-random walk through phase space.  Doing several at once would be changing the algorithm.  Moreover, when doing user-level threads, there's context switching going on, and that can slow things, making the multithreaded implementation superlinear.

Answer (score 5):

[Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) (parallelization) tells us this is not possible for the general case. At best we can perfectly divide the work by N. The reason for this is that given no serial portion, Amdahl's formula for speedup becomes:

> Speedup = 1/(1/N)

where N is the number of processors. This of course reduces to just N.

Comment: Although Amdahl's law does not consider some practical details, for example the price of context switching.

Comment: @dacc: yes if you parallelise a serial algorithm, no if you serialize a parallel one.

Comment: Amdahl's law is a very useful rule of thumb, but it is less than a complete theory of parallel computing.   As in @Jerry Coffin's answer, cache effects (or, analogously, memory bandwidth effects used when using multiple nodes) can sometimes give superlinear speedups on small numbers of processors.